# Geodesic flow on a manifold with negative curvature is ergodic

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, ergodic-theory

*This is a question asking for references.* I'm not sure if it's appropriate for StackExchange. If it's not, please tell me, thanks! :)

I'm reading about the Mostow's rigidity theorem, and the proof uses the following (maybe well-known) result:

*The geodesic flow on a manifold with negative curvature is ergodic.*

The lecture note that I'm reading does not provide a reference for that. I have some background in Riemannian geometry, but I know nothing about ergodic theory. I wanted to learn the exact meaning of this statement, and it would be even better if I could learn the proof. Can anyone give me some reference about this result? All kinds of resources are welcomed, but I would prefer to have approachable textbooks.

Thank you very much!

Comment: For references, google "geodesic flow Anosov."

Comment: @TedShifrin: Thank you so much for your help, but I'm really new to this subject and I don't know what's the relationship between Anosov and ergodic. Does Anosov property imply ergodicity? And, moreover, what's the definition of ergodic geodesic flow...? Could you please give me more hint on that? Thanks!

Comment: If you are interested in the proof of Mostow rigidity, you can certainly avoid using this result.

Comment: @SelimGhazouani: Thanks! I have read another proof by Gromov. However, I'm working on a book reading report, and the professor wants me learn about Mostow's original proof as well. If you know about that result, could you please help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: I believe that Anosov's thesis was precisely proving that Anosov flows are ergodic. This is deep stuff and I'm not an expert, either. You might look at Pugh and Shub's papers or [Ballmann's Lectures on Spaces of Nonpositive Curvature](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.psu.edu%2Fpetrunin%2Fpapers%2Fakp-papers%2Fballmann-lect.pdf&ei=gPu6Uo2sEOnO2wXF94DQDA&usg=AFQjCNERSVuf7HlxjjRye_XwpzucuQaO-Q&bvm=bv.58187178,d.b2I)

Comment: @TedShifrin: Thank you so much!